# Popup window Control template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button and Popup window with a ListBox. The data source and button commands I take from the ViewModel. I need a few more of these buttons with other sources for the ListBox and other VM buttons command. How do I reuse this code without Ctr+C Ctrl+V ? How to create Control/Data template for this Popup?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"       
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ToggleButton Content="Districts..." x:Name="DistrictButton"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=DistrictButton}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=DistrictButton}" StaysOpen="True">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Padding="10">
                <Grid Width="400" Height="300">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterModel.Districts}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Select all" Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding SelectAllDistrictsCommand}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="OK" Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding OKDistrictsCommand}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="Cancel" Margin="5,10,0,0" Command="{Binding CancelDistrictsCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Popup again with another DataSource -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you take a look at usercontrol.

Comment: Define the Border element in a UserControl and add dependency properties for the source collection and the commands to this one.

Comment: If i create UserControl how to create my Width and Height propery and set it?